# Can't figure out "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'"

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using Python 3.6 in Spyder. I am trying to insert a column before all of the other columns in an excel spread sheet and put the date in that column, in this case "2010-01". When I run the code I get the error ;"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'";.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = []
for f in ['C:\\file.xls']:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'dspPrintOrExcel')
    data.index = [os.path.basename(f)]*len(data)

class Column(object):
        def Date(self):
            print ("2010-01")

thing = Column()

df = df.insert(0, thing.Date)
df.to_excel("C:\\file2.xls")
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `Column` class?

Answer (score 2):

`df.insert()` is not returning a dataframe. Just change this line:

`df = df.insert(0,thing.Date)`

to:

`df.insert(0,thing.Date)`

Answer (score 1):

So a few things that need to be changed/fixed:

- Syntax for your
   `df = df.insert(0,thing.Date)` needs to change to `df.insert(0,thing.Date)`
- Your `def Date():` function doesn't actually do anything in the code. A print statement will output to the console so you can visually see what it's doing. But right now it's not returning anything usable when you do your insert. Fix that by adding the following:
     `def Date(self):
      print ("2010-01")
      return "2010-01"`
- Finally, the last issue with your code is the fact that you are trying to use the pandas package function .to_excel() on a list. The list df doesn't have a 
  '.to_excel' function that can run on it. You have to use a Pandas dataframe object and to do that we have to convert your list into a dataframe like so:
  `pd.DataFrame(df).to_excel("C:\\file2.xls")`

So finally your code will look like this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = []
for f in ['C:\\file.xls']:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'dspPrintOrExcel')
    data.index = [os.path.basename(f)]*len(data)

class Column(object):
        def Date(self):
            print ("2010-01")  # I kept your print in case you still wanted it
            return "2010-01"

thing = Column()

df.insert(0,thing.Date())

pd.DataFrame(df).to_excel("C:\\file2.xls")
```

Comment: Using these changes I am no longer running into the errors that I was before, but when I open the file that it created the only thing that is there is  "2010-01" in cell B2 and everything else is blank. I want to keep the original data but shift all of the existing cells one column to the right and put "2010-01" in every row of the new blank column. Is there something wrong with how I am uploading the file?